# Why do I get an 'int' object is not iterable ERROR in pyhton statistics?

Tags: python, python-3.x, statistics

So I'm working on a school exercise with python jupyter and I'm supposed to write a function that calculates the regression_coefficients out of two lists of integers or floatingpoints(Iguess) (list are arguments x and y). So i wrote the code and when I run it i get a TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable. And I know there are a lot of topics about this particular error but I can't find a solution for myself, becauss x and y only contain lists of integers so i don't get why its not iterable. Can someone please help me, I have a deadline tomorrow :( .

Ps: Here's my code -->

```
    def regression_coefficients(x,y):
    """ This function calculates the regression offset(a) and the slope(b)
        X and Y are both list of integers or floatingpoints
    """
    Xi_keer_Yi = []
    Xi_kwadraat = [nummer ** 2 for nummer in x]
    
    for x, y in zip(x, y):
        Xi_keer_Yi.append(x * y)
        
    
    Xi_keer_Yi_som = sum(Xi_keer_Yi)
    Xi_kwadraat_som = sum(Xi_kwadraat)
    X_som = sum(x)
    Y_som = sum(y)
    
    if x < y:
        n = len(x)
    elif y < x:
        n = len(y)
    else:
        n = len(x)
        
    b_boven = n * Xi_keer_Yi_som - X_som * Y_som
    b_onder = n * Xi_kwadraat_som - (X_som)**2
    
    b = b_boven / b_onder
    
    a = y[0] - (b * x[0])
    
    
    
    return a,b
    
    
print(regression_coefficients([1,2,3],[2,1,3]))
#test functie
#Test.test_regressie.test(regression_coefficients)
```

This is the error -->

```
<ipython-input-17-b8ba668746c1> in <module>
     35 
     36 
---> 37 print(regression_coefficients([1,2,3],[2,1,3]))
     38 # test functie
     39 #Test.test_regressie.test(regression_coefficients)

<ipython-input-17-b8ba668746c1> in regression_coefficients(x, y)
     13     Xi_keer_Yi_som = sum(Xi_keer_Yi)
     14     Xi_kwadraat_som = sum(Xi_kwadraat)
---> 15     X_som = sum(x)
     16     Y_som = sum(y)
     17 

TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Comment: No, they don't. You overwrite `x` and `y` here: `for x, y in zip(x, y):`. Don't do that. Use `i` and `j` or something

Comment: Thank you a lot. I fixed it :)